# Average of $(1+X)^{-1}$

Tags: probability

$X$ has the Poisson distribution with parameter $λ$.

I want to find the average of $(1+X)^{-1}$

Some steps-of-thought would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you want to find the expectation of the random variable $Y=\frac{1}{1+X}$?

Comment: 2 upvotes for a question with no attempts, kidding me right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the same type of question I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497643/compute-the-mean-of-1-x-1).

Hint: You need to write $E(1 + X)^{-1}$ in series.  Then, evaluate.  There is no tricky algebra involved.