# $E\left(\frac{1}{1+X}\right)$ for possion distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Attempt to find $E\left(\dfrac{1}{1+X}\right)$ for Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$:

$$E\left(\frac{1}{1+X}\right) = \sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{x}}{x!(x+1)}$$

$$= \frac{1}{\lambda}\sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{x+1}}{(x+1)!}$$

$= \dfrac{1}{\lambda}$ as the sigma just sums to $1.$

But this doesn't appear to be the correct answer as per my textbook, is there something I'm overlooking? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compute the mean of $(1 + X)^{-1}$ where $X$ is Poisson$(\lambda)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497643/compute-the-mean-of-1-x-1-where-x-is-poisson-lambda)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have got one key part wrong at the end.

Indeed, when you write $\frac 1{\lambda} \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^{x+1}}{(x+1)!}$, the sum is **not** $1$, since the sum might go over $x = 0$ to $\infty$ but here we have $\mathbf{x+1}$ as the variable, not $x$, in the Poisson summation. So, we are actually skipping the term in the sum which corresponds to $0$. We must account for this.

So infact, the summation is actually $1 - \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^0}{0!} = 1 - e^{-\lambda}$, thence giving the answer $\frac{1 - e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda}$, which should be correct.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: you are welcome!